# Partial skeletons in blocks bins?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Version 0.44.12-r1.

85 dwarfs fortress.

During an inspection, I have found partial skeletons in several bins of a wood blocks stockpile. e.g. "(Ngom Gaxunguslu's partial skeleton)". They are forbidden. I am not sure whether they come from a dwarf or not.

1. how do I tell from which creature they come?
2. do they have an effect on my dwarves if they see them? (e.g. like seeing a corpse?!)
3. is there a way to prevent those remains from getting in those
   places? or how can I find them and clean them 'en masse'?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I think I built the stockpile on top of a previous dump zone (yes, I *did* build a 11x11 dump zone but I recovered my sanity since, hopefully). This explains why the skeletons were forbidden, because I dumped them in the first place.

That answers point 3 of the questions above. If anybody has clue for 1 & 2 he gets the answer vote :)